# How can I make Oracle session time length limit with ODP.NET C#

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I want to know how to Oracle kill session in limited length of time
on ODP.Net.

Thease are what I tryed.
1.I made Oracle user profile set CONNECT_TIME = 1 min.
2.I made Oracle user with this profile.
3.I made C# Console AP with ODP as below.
4.Run AP.
5.Stop Afte conn.Open();
6.Keep Wait till spend more than 1 min.
7.Continue Run AP.
8.Exception occurred on reader.Read();
ex.message is Oracle is already disconnected.
And I can find Oracle Session is disappeared.
This is fine.

The problem is If I don't Continue Run AP(#7),
Then there is no Exception.
Without Exception occurred Oracle didn't kill session.

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

class Test1
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("connect string"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select id from test_table"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                        Console.WriteLine(reader["id"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To automatically kill sessions that have been connected for longer than one minute, you need to set profile limits for both CONNECT_TIME and IDLE_TIME, and you must use `(ENABLE=BROKEN)` in the connection string. With those three settings, an old session will have its `V$SESSION.STATUS` set to `KILLED` and any relevant transactions will be rolled back.

The status of `KILLED` means that most of the session resources were freed. For example, any uncommitted transactions were rolled back. However, the session still exists in `V$SESSION` and Oracle has no built-in mechanism to completely destroy those sessions. If you absolutely need those rows removed, you'll need to either force the client to try to run a command, or you'll need to create a job to run a PL/SQL command or an operating system command. Some sources claim that Oracle's PMON process will eventually cleanup the sessions entirely, but I am not able to reproduce that behavior on 19c Enterprise Edition on Windows 10 Pro.

Killing Oracle sessions has always been kind of a pain, and trying *too hard* to kill sessions can cause problems. I recommend that you lower your expectations and accept that `STATUS='KILLED'` is good enough.

Below is some sample code for creating and applying the relevant profile, and how to connect with SQL*Plus. I'm not sure exactly how to format the connection for C# though.

```
create profile test_profile limit connect_time 1 idle_time 1;
create user test_user identified by test_user profile test_profile;

D:\>sqlplus test_user/test_user@"(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host_name_here)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orclpdb.Home)))"
```

Comment: Thank you, Jon, for a perfect answer.
I did exactly what you commented. I changed my Oracle User's Profile CONNECT_TIME and IDLE_TIME to 1 minute, and I modified the connection string in C# as follows:

string conString = "User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;" +
"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyOracleIP)(PORT=1521))" +
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=MyOracleInstance)));";

Oracle session was automatically killed after 1 minute and 50 seconds in my case.